# jQuery : Toggle Sliding A div from left to right over another div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to slide a partially hidden div (placed using `margin-right: -300px;` to the element and `overflow-x: hidden;` to the parent. Here is the code I have used:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="first">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>

    <div class="second">
        <!-- Content -->
    <div class="third">
        <img class="ttoggle" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/21jc3o1.png">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And, the CSS

```
.entry-content {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 1140px;
}

.first {
    float: left;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 10px;
    width : 560px;
}
.second {
    float: left;
    heoght: 1000px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 475px;
}
.third {
    float: left;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 -300px 0 0;
}
```

Now, the every tutorial I came across either not working, or just pulling the div from left making it go down below the first two divs because of the insufficient available width.

**My goal is to pull the div on top of the second div without breaking the layout.** So, I am completely lost here with my little knowledge in jQuery.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve. I hope this explains what I tried to achieve.

[image: Sliding DIV from Right on Top of another]

Can this be done using jQuery? I certainly don't want anyone to do the job for me, but any help, or even something to play with will be much appreciated.

Comment: `float` is your problem. Having two divs side by side using `float` is fine, just as long as you're not trying to animate them. Try using `position: absolute;` and animating the `left` or `right` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning. Absolutely positioned objects are placed wherever specified using top/right/bottom/left relative to the origin or the closest relatively positioned parent.

So, first, add `position: relative` to `.entry-content` so that the sidebar is positioned relative to it. Then you can add this CSS to `.third`:

```
position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: 100;
```

Then to animate it in you can do something like this:

```
$('.third').click(function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this),
        r = parseInt($this.css('right'), 10);

    $this.animate({right: r ? 0 : 300}, 1000);
});
```

### [See Rough Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj73F/)